# MS-ACCESS monitoring rows

Tags: ms-access

I capture a lot of data I need to analyze and see if it's new (not in the last capture), if is finished (not in the next capture) or else would be pending...

The rows can change some columns, but there are some that don't change.
Those captures are weekly and are marked and stored.
In excel I would concatenate the non changing rows and if vlookup using the date of the capture +/-7 to see if it's new, finished or pending... (one column to compare next and other to compare last)

I'm trying to convert it to access, since there are over 30000 rows each week and excel is becoming sluggish...

I made a query, then I concatenated the columns, show the date... but not sure how to go from there... 
I used dateadd and made many columns, each to it's purpose... i just have no idea how to make access check all records...

I have the now column (date+concatenate), then the lastweek and nextweek

I then used iif(now=last;"pending";"new") and iif(now=next;"pending";"finished")

It don't seem to be checking all records... everything goes as new and finished... I'm doing something wrong or it just don't work like that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Access doesn't like to reference new columns in a query.  Try breaking it up into 2 queries.  Create one query where you add your new fields (Now, Last and Next).  However, I think all 3 of those names are "reserved words", so call them something else (maybe "dNow", "dNext" and "dLast").  Then create a second query where you check if dNow = dNext.  Also, in your IIF statement make sure you're using commas and not semi-colons.

Comment: In your IIf statement, "now" calls the `Now()` function. `Now()` returns the date *and* time, down to the second. This means `Now()` is very unlikely to equal any values in the `next` or `last` fields, which I assume are plain date fields (no time). Use the `Today()` function, which returns just the date part. Oh, and follow Johnny's advice on naming.

Comment: Those names are just to be easy to understand here... they have more appropriate names in there. There was however one problem... even after breaking in 2 queries, it still don't work... no idea why.... I started playing doing the same with a dlookup... and still no luck.

Comment: I believe, with IIF it thinks only in the row, not the column... meaning it would be always false... is there any way to force access to see one "cell" or a column?